# Behaviour of custom scope in constructor-injection Spring

Tags: java, spring

following is my use-case :

There are two configuration class.

ClientConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public DeleteFiles deleteFiles() {
         return new DeleteFiles();
     }
}
```

UserConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class UserConfig {
   
    @Autowired
    private DeleteFiles deleteFiles;

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer registerWorkflowScope() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        customScopeConfigurer.addScope("workflow", new WorkflowScope());
        return customScopeConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("workflow")
    public RandomClass fn() {
        return new RandomClass(deleteFiles);
    }
}
```

1. How will DeleteFiles behave in terms of scope? Will a new object of DeleteFiles will get created for each new workflow?
2. Is there any way to test the behaviour of scope of DeleteFiles either by some unit-tests or some other way.
3. Can we use @Scope("workflow") on deleteFiles bean, as it is in different configuration class.

Comment: What do you mean "how will it behave"? It's a singleton bean that you can inject or autowire into any other spring managed component or service.

Comment: And you unit test it the usual way in the ClientConfig unit tests, and the DeleteFiles's unit tests, and usually inject a mock into the other places where you've autowired/injected it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, beans that you create a singletons. That means that every single place you inject it (autowired or otherwise), it's the same instance that is used.

You can change this by specifying the *scope* of your bean -- "prototype" scope allows for multiple instance objects, an a unique instance is created every time it is requested. There are other scopes as well, such as "reqest" which is scoped to the lifetime of an HTTP request. For more information, you can refer to the [Spring documentation on bean scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes), or this [Baeldung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes).

In your example, your ClientConfig declares a DeleteFiles bean. When Spring processes that configuration, it follows your instructions in how to instantiate and configure this bean, and then adds it to its bean registry. When it later processes the UserConfig, it sees that you have autowired an instance of DeleteFiles, so it takes that instance in its registry and assigns it to that variable. If you were to create a component that used constructor injection to pass an instance of DeleteFiles, it would pass that same instance from Spring's repository of beans into that constructor.

To specify a different scope (eg Prototype), you use the [`@Scope` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html):

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
Foo example() { ... }
```

For testing, the usual workflow is to write regular unit tests for the DeleteFiles class, write tests to verify correct instantiation of the bean for the ClientConfig class, and to inject a mock instance into the UserConfig tests (or any other places where you use the bean.) Then you can stub out or mock all of the calls on the DeleteFiles instance mock.

Comment: Got it. Thanks .  Just one query: If we need to use the @Scope("workflow") on deleteFiles bean, is that possible because the customScope is defined in different configuration class. and how to test if the correct scope is added  for Workflow scope.

Comment: There is a section on how to create and use a custom scope in the Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom).